# How to open an existing message (email) programmatically on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to open an existing message from my application so that the native email client can display the content of said message, but I cannot find any way to do that. I have found a way to open a newly created message with

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGE,
       new MessageArguments (MessageArguments.ARG_NEW, "to", "subject", "body"));
```

But trying to open an existing message triggers an ObjectGroupReadOnlyException.

So, how can I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to display a message (using the native email app) from a different app. Basically: provide a different inbox view, but when the user selects an email, send him to the native email app with the email opened.

In any case, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Blackberry SDK samples you can find a demo app using which you can understand how to read your inbox using your own application

The name of the demo is **BlackberryMailDemo**